# React Three Fiber striped shadow

Tags: javascript, next.js, three.js, react-three-fiber

I am currently building a simple 3D object viewer website using Next.js and React-Three-Fiber. Everything works fine until I put an instance of DirectionalLight and make all meshes to receive shadow.

[image: Object shadows become striped]

I tried everything including changing the `dpr` parameter of the Fiber's `Canvas`, but seems nothing worked for me.

My Canvas:

```js
<Canvas shadows={true} dpr={[1, 2]} orthographic camera={{ zoom: 200, position: [0, 5, 10] }}>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <OrbitControls enableDamping enableZoom />
        <Model
            position={[0, -1, 0]}
            scale={[0.4, 0.4, 0.4]} 
            receiveShadow
        />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
        <directionalLight
            castShadow
            ref={directionalLightRef}
            shadowMapHeight={1024}
            shadowMapWidth={1024}
            shadowCameraFar={50}
            shadowBias={-0.05}
            intensity={1}
            position={[1.5, 5, 7]}
        />
    </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in three.js and what fixed it for me was to change all my shadow Normal Bias (not the shadowBias) to a lower value like 0.06. I'm still trying to figure out how to access the shadow Normal Bias in ReactThreeFiber

edit: shadow-normalBias={0.06}